# Firebase sign in and sign up with email and password for flutter issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have connect my flutter app with firebase. then, I implement Signin and Signup(new user creation)screens with email and password . sign in is works fine and its redirect to home page. and the actual problem is with the signup page route, it cannot redirect into homepage but the values are stored in to the firebase !! anyone give me a solution????

login page

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery_app/screens/signup/signup_screen.dart';
import '../../config/constants.dart';
import '../../config/theme.dart';
import '../../utils/helper.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            Helper.getAssetName("bg-home.jpg", "virtual"),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
          htspace40,
          SizedBox(
              child: Text(
            'UAE\' Most Reliable Food \nDelivery and Dining App',
            style: AppTextStyle.boldSpaceBlack(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )),
          htspace20,
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Log In',
                  style: AppTextStyle.light20(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                htspace20,
                Material(
                  elevation: 12,
                  shadowColor: AppColors.shadowTxt,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 320,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                        ),
                        label: const Text(
                          'Email',
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.txt),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                htspace20,
                Material(
                  elevation: 12,
                  shadowColor: AppColors.shadowTxt,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 320,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                        ),
                        label: const Text(
                          'Password',
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.txt),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text('Don\'t have an account?'),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignUpScreen()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text('Sign up'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 284.0,
                  height: 40,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // <-- Radius
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: isLoading
                          ? const SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 30,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  strokeWidth: 3, color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          : const Text('Sign in'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = true;
                        });
                        signIn();
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (emailController.text != " " ||
                                passwordController.text != " ") {
                              isLoading = false;
                            } else {
                              isLoading = true;
                            }
                          });
                        });
                      }),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'or',
            style: AppTextStyle.regular14(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          htspace20,
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: AppColors.txt, width: 1.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      Helper.getAssetName("google.png", "virtual"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: AppColors.txt, width: 1.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      Helper.getAssetName("apple.png", "virtual"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: AppColors.txt, width: 1.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.more_horiz_rounded,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Stack(children: [
                const Align(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'By Continuing, you agree to our',
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0, right: 0.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Terms of Service',
                          style: AppTextStyle.regular10(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          ' Privacy Policy',
                          style: AppTextStyle.regular10(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Content Policies',
                          style: AppTextStyle.regular10(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future signIn() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Email or Password Incorrect');
    }
  }
}
```

signup page

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery_app/screens/login/login_screen.dart';
import '../../config/constants.dart';
import '../../config/theme.dart';
import '../../utils/helper.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            Helper.getAssetName("bg-home.jpg", "virtual"),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
          htspace40,
          SizedBox(
              child: Text(
            'UAE\' Most Reliable Food \nDelivery and Dining App',
            style: AppTextStyle.boldSpaceBlack(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )),
          htspace20,
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Sign Up',
                  style: AppTextStyle.light20(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                htspace20,
                Material(
                  elevation: 12,
                  shadowColor: AppColors.shadowTxt,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 320,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                        ),
                        label: const Text(
                          'Email',
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.txt),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                htspace20,
                Material(
                  elevation: 12,
                  shadowColor: AppColors.shadowTxt,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 320,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                        ),
                        label: const Text(
                          'Password',
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.txt),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text('Already have an account?'),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25),
                            child: const Text('login'),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 284.0,
                  height: 40,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // <-- Radius
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: isLoading
                          ? const SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                              width: 30,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  strokeWidth: 3, color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          : const Text('Sign up'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // setState(() {
                        //   isLoading = true;
                        // });
                        signUp();
                        // Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                        //   setState(() {
                        //     if (emailController.text != " " ||
                        //         passwordController.text != " ") {
                        //       isLoading = false;
                        //     } else {
                        //       isLoading = true;
                        //     }
                        //   });
                        // });
                      }),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'or',
            style: AppTextStyle.regular14(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          htspace20,
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: AppColors.txt, width: 1.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      Helper.getAssetName("google.png", "virtual"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: AppColors.txt, width: 1.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      Helper.getAssetName("apple.png", "virtual"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: AppColors.txt, width: 1.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.more_horiz_rounded,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Stack(children: [
                const Align(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'By Continuing, you agree to our',
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0, right: 0.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Terms of Service',
                          style: AppTextStyle.regular10(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          ' Privacy Policy',
                          style: AppTextStyle.regular10(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Content Policies',
                          style: AppTextStyle.regular10(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future signUp() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Email or Password Incorrect');
    }
  }
}
```

home page

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery_app/screens/signup/signup_screen.dart';

import '../../config/theme.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const SignUpScreen();
          }
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                'Home',
                style: AppTextStyle.bold(),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                  splashRadius: 20,
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: const Center(
              child: Text('Homeeee'),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: After sign up user should sign in right?Then only user should redirect to homePage.You are expecting when user sign up and firebase auth state will change and redirect to home page which is not correct I guess.. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: When a user signs up with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, the user is signed in if the account is created successfully. Since the StreamBuilder listens for authStateChanges, check the snapshot.data for the User value. The StreamBuilder should automatically rebuild once change in authStateChanges Stream has been detected.